# How does CSS Modules cascade work? Some styles from props aren't applied

Tags: css, next.js, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm having some issues with CSS Modules in the way how the resulting files are loaded when accessing a page (it's a Next JS project).

I have a Button component in `src/components/Button` which has its own css module file. In a page component I have another component that's using the Button component.

In this component the button needs to have additional styles so I pass these styles per props. i.e: the text has to be bigger

```
<Button className={styles.bigText} />
```

In the Button component I do this:

```
import classnames from 'classnames'
import styles from './styles.module.css'

function Button({ children, className }) {
  const classes = classnames(styles.button, className);

  return <Button className={classes}>{ children }</Button>
}
```

When the page reloads I see the button rendered with the font-size defined in the Button's styles file and `bigText` appears overwritten, so it's not applied.

I tried to use `composes` for importing the class `button` from Button's style file but still the font-size applied is the value set in the `.button` class.

```css
.bigText {
  composes: button import './path/to/button/styles';
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

The className prop in Button component is replaced to use the className prop I pass it

```
function Button({ children, className }) {
  return <Button className={className}>{ children }</Button>
}
```

Comment: See [MDN: CSS Specificity docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Can you just show the resulting HTML and CSS? You can even make a runnable snippet using the `<>` button. This has likely nothing to do with react I'm assuming.